# PayPal integration Logger API hits on different place

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal, paypal-buttons

PayPal integration Logger API is getting hit multiple times on different places on my website where it is not even called and as a result the request gets cancelled.
I am unable to identify the cause and resolve the same.

API: https://www.paypal.com/xoplatform/logger/api/logger

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As long as you aren't loading or calling the PayPal JS SDK multiple times, you should be fine. But if you continue to have problems, contact PayPal's support. Not an issue for Stackoverflow.